# Deleting first array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been trying to delete specific parts of an array, and I thought I had it working. But I cannot figure out why I cannot delete the first record.

If I set arrayToDelete to 67(representing the first element of 2nd array), or 9(representing the first element of 3rd array)...it works as I expected. But if I change arrayToDelete to 7(representing the first element of 1st array), it doesn't remove that one.

Where am I going wrong?

```
var mainArray = [];
var a = [7,"red","Q","gtgtg"];
mainArray.push(a);
var b = [67,"blue","s","ghft"];
mainArray.push(b);
var c = [9,"green","t","rtryt"];
mainArray.push(c);
var pickle = JSON.stringify(mainArray);
console.log("starting array - "+pickle);
console.log("starting array length - "+mainArray.length);

var arrayToDelete = "67";

var getLoc = "";

// Get position of array where first value is "1"
for (var i = 0; i < mainArray.length; i++) {
    //console.log(mainArray[i][0]);
    if(mainArray[i][0] == arrayToDelete){
        //console.log("array number "+i);
        getLoc = i;
    }
}
console.log("that number was spotted in position - "+getLoc);
//Delete from
if(getLoc != "" && getLoc != "-1"){
    mainArray.splice(getLoc, 1);  
}
var pickle2 = JSON.stringify(mainArray);
console.log("Array after removal - "+pickle2);
console.log("ending array length - "+mainArray.length);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is in `getLoc != ""`. This is `false` for `getLoc === 0`.

I know js is not a strong-typed language, but you'll be better of if you write with strong-typed equality checks `===`

See e.g. this article for more insights on the subject http://www.sitepoint.com/borrowing-techniques-strongly-typed-languages-javascript/ and it's always a good choice to run your code through a static code analyzer (e.g. http://jslint.com or http://jshint.com).

Answer (score 2):

Add `console.log(getLoc != "")` before `//Delete from`, and you will see printed ***false*** when getLoc=0.

Change

```
console.log("that number was spotted in position - "+getLoc);
//console.log(getLoc != "")
//Delete from
if(getLoc != "" && getLoc != "-1"){
    mainArray.splice(getLoc, 1);  
}
```

by

```
console.log("that number was spotted in position - "+getLoc);
//console.log(getLoc !== "")
//Delete from
if(getLoc !== "" && getLoc != "-1"){
    mainArray.splice(getLoc, 1);  

}
```

Comment: Upvote for telling the OP how to discover the problem on their own.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Do you think is better to show the error than solve the issue?

Comment: Both, of course.  I was just saying that I like educational answers that, hopefully, teach people how to do their own debugging.

Comment: I agree @JeremyJStarcher

Answer (score 1):

Functional approach might be much more readable in this case:

```
mainArray = mainArray.filter(arr => arr[0] !== arrayToDelete);
```

Comment: This shares the code-fault of the original `!=` vs `!==`